# angular js directive error - Argument 'Controller' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to do some tests on a directive in Plunker.  Here's my directive, copied directly from the angular docs.  I did this just so I would have something working to start from.

```
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.customer = {
      name: 'Naomi',
      address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
     };
  })
 .directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
    template: 'Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'
  };
});
```

The html in plunker

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.25"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

    <div ng-controller="Controller">
      <div my-customer></div>
    </div>

</html>
```

And here's a link to the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/KavmY4P9V23JHBPKxPWq?p=preview
The error I'm getting in the console is Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'Controller' is not a function, got 
The controller seems to be named consistently, the only thing i can think of that would cause this error. Am I just overlooking something or is Plunker acting weird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate your module, like this:

```
<html ng-app='docsSimpleDirective'>
```

### [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TVFscqAyqnsCSTn1bHNt?p=preview)